# The Symfony Dependency Injection Container should not be passed as an argument

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

This morning, SensioLabs Insight removed the platinum badge from one of my distributed bundles.

> The Symfony Dependency Injection Container should not be passed as an argument.
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Sets the Container.
>  *
>  * @param ContainerInterface|null $container
>  */
> public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
> ```
>
> A Symfony dependency injection container has been found as an argument.

The method is part of the following service:

```
rch_jwt_user.credential_fetcher:
    class: RCH\JWTUserBundle\Service\CredentialFetcher
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, [ "@service_container" ] ]
```

I know I can pass the container as constructor argument like this:

```
rch_jwt_user.credential_fetcher:
    class: RCH\JWTUserBundle\Service\CredentialFetcher
    arguments: [ "@service_container" ]
```

But a lot of community bundles use a setter rather than the constructor.

So what is the reason of this <strike>major</strike> minor warning ?

An explanation of why/when should we prefer use a setter rather than pass the container as an argument in constructor (and the inverse) would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

In response of comments:

SLI don't care about how the container is injected, apparently it's a bad practice to inject it.

Any idea of an SLI-compliant alternative ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is the way you are injecting, for me it looks like: "If you are injecting the entire container you are not being specific on which services you need". But I'm not sure because the message is also not clear.  But trying to answer your question I would say the reason is because the constructor is the signature of the class, using setter would make more sense then!

Comment: For several reasons, I need to inject the whole container. My implementation looks like a lot of other, such as [FOSRestBundle ParamFetcher](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamFetcher.php) . Maybe I need to extends the ContainerAware or implement the corresponding Interface, I will make some tries , but I don't really understand.

Comment: I think that what Insight is trying to say is that you should try finding another way of injecting the dependencies that you need in this service. Have you tried modifying your Extension?

Comment: Thank's for your comments. 
@hasumedic What do you mean by modifying the Extension ? How can it help ? I need to access the whole container in my service because of use of different services/parameters depending on the context where/how the service is called . My question is only about what is the right way to inject the container and why my approach involves this major warning.

Comment: I mentioned the Extension in case you could set up the dependencies in there at container compilation time. If you depend on runtime data, you might indeed need to inject the container somewhere at some point. Have you asked SensioLabs directly for what they expect with warning?

Comment: No, I am on a free plan also I can't access the whole explanation which should be given for a more advanced plan, so the answer of SLI could be "subscribe a premium plan". This alternative can surely give me the answer, but too much expensive :/ . I hope someone that already experienced this issue can give me an answer.

Comment: My question is: will you still get the warning using constructor injection?  I suspect it is just a general warning against injecting the container regardless of the method.  If you really do need the entire container then you might just have to live with it.

Comment: @Cerad look at my edit. The only alternative seems to ignore the warning ...

Comment: And did you try adding implements ContainerAwareInterface?  I have no idea of the internals of the check but it's possible that if you indicate that you really mean to inject the container then maybe it will be okay.  Might also try creating a service alias for the container.

Comment: @Cerad I just tried, while the method is present (and more precisely the `$container` as argument), there is nothing to do, it's effectively a general warning. Maybe you can give me an answer of how to avoid the method in my service and keep a full access of the container ?

Comment: $kernel is of course a global variable and you could get the container from it.  But I suspect that cure would be far worse than the disease.  I assume you don't know your service id's in advance so it's impossible to inject them.  All I can suggest is to file an issue with SensioLabs and maybe they will tweak their check.

Comment: Does not extending the ContainerAware or use ContainerAwareTrait could make the `setContainer` method available in my service, in order to keep it in the `calls` of my service without code it into ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105170/discussion-between-cerad-and-chalasr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @RenatoMendesFigueiredo, @hasumedic & (the most part) @Cerad, without need of premium plan, I can see the point of this warning and figure it out.

In fact, a long time ago, I would make my service extending the [`ContainerAware`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.html) rather than write the method directly, but forced to live with its limits (the service could not have extended another class).

In 2.4, the [`ContainerAwareTrait`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareTrait.html) was added.

My guess is that the warning has been added in the same time as this trait, because :

1) No reason to write a setter or a constructor to inject the container if a trait that do it already exists.

2) No need of pass the container as an argument in an another goal than inject it to a service.

Also, I removed the `setContainer` method from the class of my service, make it use the `ContainerAwareTrait` and keep the the service definition as before.

*And ...*

[image: Kudos]

**Kudos**!